# How to open a react-native app from another app to a specific screen?

Tags: react-native

I am working on two React native Android apps and one needs to link to the other. When I click on an item in app A, app B needs to open to a screen which shows additional information about that item. I am using React native Linking for that.

However, I do not know how to configure the path to the item screen, meaning that app B always opens on the front screen.

The following code simply opens app B front screen:

`const link = "reader://?type=" + type + "&id=" + this.selectedItem.id;`

Where can I see how to configure the path correctly?

Comment: you have to give the item screen a path like: itemScreen: {
      screen: ItemScreen,
      path: 'itemScreen/:link',
    } then you can do this: const link = "reader://itemScreen/?type=" + type + "&id=" + this.selectedItem.id;

Comment: And if the ItemScreen Navigator is nested in other navigators you'd have to give everyone of them a path of '' meaning { screen: ItemScreenNavigator, path: "" }